# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

sorry for the trivial question (maybe) but I've been hitting my head for hours.
where is the mistake?

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { SingleCoin } from '../config/api';

const {id} = useParams();
const [coins, setCoins] = useState();
const {currency, symbol} = CryptoState();
    
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchCoins = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(SingleCoin(id));
        setCoins(data);
    };
    fetchCoins();
}, []);
```

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any variable that you use in the `useEffect` function needs to be in the dependency array, so that it is can be monitored and the useEffect will only be run when that variable changes.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchCoins = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(SingleCoin(id));
        setCoins(data);
    };
    fetchCoins();
}, [id]);
```

Add `id` to the array that is the second parameter of `useEffect` to clear this error.
[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Despite the addition of `id`, `coins` are worth `undefined`. Yet the api does work. Did I make an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect and some other hooks need a dependency array provided. It's the last argument passed as an array. The dependencies tell the hooks which variables or elements to observe for changes. If a dependency changes, the hook should also expect a new behavior and will therefor update.

To fix your issue, you need to provide the id in your dependency array as the warning states like so:
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchCoins = async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(SingleCoin(id));
        setCoins(data);
    };
    fetchCoins();
}, [id]);
```